# Error [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000 while executing the testsuite through Selenium on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, selenium-chromedriver

I use ChromeDriver with Selenium to run my automated tests. The test suite runs successfully in both Eclipse and command line. However, it does not run when I try to build it in Jenkins.

This is my job config in Jenkins (all info has names sanitized for confidentiality):
[image]
I can confirm it's Ant is running JDK8.

This is the console output of the build:

```
[junit] Running main.TESTNAME
    [junit] Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 27352
    [junit] Only local connections are allowed.
    [junit] Apr 26, 2018 3:52:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    [junit] INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    [junit] Running through test suite as:
    [junit] User: USERNAME
    [junit] URL: CONFIDENTIAL
    [junit] [30.168][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000
    [junit] [30.170][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003
    [junit] Total number of tests ran for TESTNAME: 5, Number of tests failures: 4, Number of tests ignored: 0
    [junit] testViewProfileDetailsButtonAndBrowseBack(test.TESTNAME): timeout
    [junit]   (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.119)
    [junit]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    [junit] Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    [junit] Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
    [junit] System info: host: 'PC', ip: 'IP', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
    [junit] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    [junit] Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286..., userDataDir: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir1...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 64.0.3282.119, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

My `build.xml` below is mostly auto-generated except for the end where I added JUnit integration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="PROJECTSeleniumTest">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.8"/>
<property name="source" value="1.8"/>
<path id="PROJECTSeleniumTest.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/byte-buddy-1.7.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/client-combined-3.8.1-sources.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/client-combined-3.8.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-exec-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/gson-2.8.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/guava-23.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/httpcore-4.4.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project,junit" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="PROJECTSeleniumTest.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="create_directory">
    <echo message="Create the directory JenkinsTestReports\" />
    <mkdir dir="JenkinsTestReports" />
</target>   

<target name="junit" depends="create_directory">
    <echo message="${java.version}"/>
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="PROJECTSeleniumTest.classpath" />
            <pathelement location="${basedir}\bin"/>
        </classpath>
        <batchtest todir="JenkinsTestReports" fork="true">
          <fileset dir="${basedir}\bin">
            <include name="main\TESTNAME.class"/>
          </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Does anyone know what the cause might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
[30.168][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate a new *Chrome* browser process.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=64.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64** (*includes the browser version you are using*)

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.8.1**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_151** which is pretty older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u151* , *Selenium Client v3.8.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.33* and *Chrome Browser v64.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Due to my workplace restricting my Chrome versioning, I cannot upgrade it past v64 at this time. I also cannot install unapproved software. However, I did update: _ChromeDriver to 2.37 (which supports Chrome v64), Selenium to 3.11, jobs JDK to 1.8.0_171._

It still runs unsuccessfully.

As I said my ant build works in both the command line and Eclipse prior to updating these. There's only an incompatibility with Jenkins. 

Do you think it's still an incompatibility with versions if I have proof of it executing elsewhere? They run in different minor versions but they're still 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Remove timeout solved this problem for me :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout
```

Like

```
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
//driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```