# python selenium not running with chrome driver & chrome version

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a project in selenium with chrome driver, but after I didn't use it for a month ( Was an update to chrome).
When I run the project its opens thechrome browser and then immediately closes.

I reciving the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\maorb\OneDrive\Desktop\Maor\python\serethd\tvil_arthur.py", line 27, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 91, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in start_session
>       'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
>   from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

I am using chrome web driver version `2.36` & Google chrome  version `63.0.3239.10`

I tried to use latest Chrome & Chrome webdriver version but Its opening the chrome but its just opening and not doing any of code.

Comment: Check your _chrome_ version once again and update

Comment: Is it possible to use latest version of web driver and chrome? Or are you restricted to update?
Usually the version of web driver works well with its intended version of Chrome Browser. Sometimes, changes in chrome browser can cause breaking changes to web driver. 
Try to update both to latest version. If the issue still persists, then it's probably something else

Comment: @DebanjanB I was in the last update but its still not working so I tried to downrage but now its still not working.

Comment: @DebanjanB When I am using Chrome & Chrome webdriver latest versions its opening the chrome when I run it but Its just opening and nothing else ( saying new tab of chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error \[SEVERE\]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000 while executing the testsuite through Selenium on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin)

Comment: @DebanjanB its not duplicate

Comment: @kaki Try to downgrade crome driver, 2 or 3 versions.Then try again. If y can, downgrade chrome browser as well. They've made changes(Google) on new versions, and they are not stable when y interact with them with automation scripts/programs.

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov not working

Comment: @kaki Remove window size set keywords if you are using any in your tests, and try again. Also download driver from here; 
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

Answer (score 0):

Usually people get this error when your script cannot find the chromedriver maybe re look at where you specified the path to be and add a executable path

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version of the both Chrome and Selenium WebDriver and Check the Compatiblity of the both according to them.

After that you can try the Below Code according to your requirement like where the your driver is located and which site you want to open.

```
service = Service(executable_path='C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Edge(service=service)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

And Add the Packages