# Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get status of transactions from some web portal and I am using below chrome settings in my java application and I am getting

> Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000

and all the pending transactions are timing out.

Session info: headless **chrome=68.0.3440.75**
Driver info: **chromedriver=2.38** (0)
platform=Linux 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64)

How i can handle this and if any timeout is happening then move to next transaction?

I have tried all permutation and combinations with below statements but still its not working;

```
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- You are using *chrome=68.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.
- Your *JDK version* is version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the  *ChromeDriver v2.38* and the *Chrome Browser v68.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v67-69*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: I still get this issue:  `ChromeDriver 2.42` `jdk 1.8` `selenium 3.14` `chrome 69`

Comment: This answer is on two different questions([other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin)) both time resulting in the asker saying this solution doesn't work. Nice to point out they are using the wrong driver/chrome version but it does not resolve the question. I also have this issue with with compatible driver and chrome version.