# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

Tags: java, selenium, docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting following error when running my scenarios.

> **org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving
>   message from renderer: 10.000**
>
> (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79) Build info: version: '3.14.0',
>   revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info:
>   host: 'fv-az598', ip: '10.1.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '4.15.0-1064-azure', java.version: '1.8.0_212' Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, ***browserVersion:
>   79.0.3945.79***, chrome: {***chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36***

As you can see, with bold, highlighted font, I do have matching versions of the chrome and chrome driver.

I am also passing some arguments to my ChromeOptions that meant help with timeouts:

```
        // options to prevent TIMEOUTS
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283818/1689770
        options.addArguments("enable-automation"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123152/1689770
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959986/how-to-solve-selenium-chromedriver-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exc
        options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor"); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373625/getting-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-600-000-when-we-execute-selen
```

Edit: it happens when running in DOCKER container (using LATEST docker images for chrome browser, and node-chrome-debug)

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give more details?, because it can be internet connection, also you can try to put a thread sleep

Comment: @Matthewek Can you upgrade your Chrome browser to current _...Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build)..._?

Comment: @DebanjanB - sorry, i did not mention (edited post now) that it happens when I run them in docker, using LATEST images for all services (browser and chrome driver) so I am using latest (newest available) docker images. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.14.0* of *2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z* which is almost **1.5** years older andthe concurrent *ChromeDriver* was **OSS** compliant.
- You are using *chromedriver=79.0*
- You are using *chrome=79.0*
- Though *chromedriver=79.0* and *chrome=79.0* are concurrent but they are incompatible with *Selenium Client* version is *3.14.0*.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.14.0* , *ChromeDriver v79.0* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017854/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer/52033769#52033769)
- [Error [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000 while executing the testsuite through Selenium on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, indeed my selenium version was outdated and it was contributing factor, updating selenium to version 3.141.59 did not help initially, but combining it with additional ChromeOptions being passed (--disable-features=NetworkService, --dns-prefetch-disable, --disable-extensions) it all works well now, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It because either you have set pageload timeout to 10 sec
example

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

change here 10 to any other number to see increase in timeout

or

delete that line if no needed