# How to fix the error: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10 using Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, renderer

First of all, I want to say that I already read / applied all fixes listed on StackOverflow related to the same question and they do not work in my case, that's why I opened up a new one.

I am using selenium grid (4.0) with a chrome node (docker containers)

I am doing some screen captures on some sites, and running everything using Behat

Everything is fine, until I get to one page that is really big in height, and I want to capture the mobile version of it (which ends up being 120.000px in height)

That's when I see the following error in logs:

```
capture-service-chrome | [1648642983.839][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
capture-service-chrome | [1648642983.843][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

I've already added everything I possible could in my Behat file

```
            idleTimeout: 20000
            pageLoadStrategy: none
            timeouts: {implicit: 20000, pageLoad: 20000, script: 20000}
            chromeOptions:
              args:
                - "--no-sandbox"
                - "--headless"
                - "--disable-gpu"
                - "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
                - "--no-proxy-server"
                - "--disable-extensions"
                - "--dns-prefetch-disable"
                - "--force-device-scale-factor=1"
                - "--disable-infobars"
                - "--disable-browser-side-navigation"
                - "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
                - "--window-size=1920,1080"
                - "--log-level=3"
                - "enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess"
                - "disable-features=NetworkService"
```

The versions that I am using are: browserVersion: 93.0.4577.82, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 93.0.4577.82)

I really dont see what else I can do. The same page is captured properly on desktop (eg bigger width, smaller height), but when I try to capture using mobile resolution (320xHEIGHT) .. it crashes

I know the problem comes from the height, resizing the browser takes some time or something, but is there a way to fix it?

P.S: something weird that I've noticed, is that if I try to capture a page that is 1400x10.000 lets say, and I force it to 1400x120.000, it captures it (adding blank space at the bottom of course), but I get an image with 120k px in height at least ... so what's wrong when capturing a smaller width?

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium 4.0 (latest one)

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
capture-service-chrome | [1648642983.839][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
capture-service-chrome | [1648642983.843][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

---

### Reason

Though you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.0*** but

- [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) version is ***93.0.4577.82***
- *Google-chrome* version is ***93.0.4577.82***

which are very old and ancient with respect to the current Selenium version of **4.0**

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.1.3***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=98.0.4758.48 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.48/notes.txt)).

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Timed out receiving message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033769/7429447)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution! Unfortunately, the problem still persists. I've upgraded to: ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60, Google Chrome 100.0.4896.60,  Started Selenium Standalone 4.1.3, and I still have the exact same error. As I've said, something is weird, since I load the page, do a capture for 1400x30864 and it works, then resize to 320x112000 and when I try to do a capture it times out (while executing ->getScreenshot()). The weird thing is that if I resize to 1400x112000 (this means that after the 30864px I'll have just white space), I can capture it .. but not 320x112000px